# CSS help. Make validation message appear next to the input field

Tags: html, css

I have a validation message under the field, but I want it to be on the same line.
( Please don't judjge my Front-End skills, specially css and html =)   )

## now

[image]

## what I want

[image]

## CSS

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";

#reg-form {
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
}

#reg-form li {
    width: 250px;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 5px;
}

    #reg-form li label {
        width: 150px;
        float: left;
    }

.status {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: red;

}

#register-user {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 7px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

## HTML

```
{% block main-menu %} 
    <div class="contentarea">
            <form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
                <ul id="reg-form">
                    <li>
                        <label for="id_username">Username:</label>
                        <input id="id_username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" />
                    </li>
                    <div class="status"></div>
                    <li>
                        <label for="id_email">Email:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="id_email" />
                    </li>
                    <div class="status"></div>
                    <li>
                        <label for="id_password">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" />
                    </li>
                    <div class="status"></div>
                    <li>
                        <label for="id_password2">Password (Again):</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password2" id="id_password2" />
                    </li>
                    <div class="status"></div>
                </ul>
                <input type="button" value="register" id="register-user"/>
            </form>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<li>`s have `display: block;` on them. Try changing it to `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` on `.status` and `#reg-form li`. See http://jsfiddle.net/Q7R4k/. Inline elements will by default stack to the right, while block takes up the whole horizontal line.

You'll need to have line breaks between the `li`s, though, to get the `li`s on separate lines. See http://jsfiddle.net/Q7R4k/1/.

**EDIT:**
See http://jsfiddle.net/Q7R4k/2/ for a version with div's directly after the inputs. Here, the labels are given `display:block;`, the inputs `display:inline-block;` (inline would work too) and `.status` `display:inline;`. Also, the width of the `ul` is taken out.

Comment: This is still invalid syntax. :(

Comment: @EthanB Edited. This gets rid of the invalid `div`, I believe.

Comment: Much better! :D (Might as well use `<span>`s, though.)

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't put `<div>`s inside a `<ul>` -- it's bad syntax. (Javascript errors come with bad syntax.) Tip: check your source code with [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Try using `<span>`--which is an inline element--instead of `<div>` (but put the spans inside the corresponding `<li>`s).

For example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q7R4k/3/

Comment: You're welcome. (I've been bitten by malformed HTML before. Make sure it validates!)

Comment: Can you please explain why span is better for this situation than div?

Comment: By default, `span` is an inline element. `div` is a block element. You can change these defaults with CSS, but it means you have one more style to define.